The conductor of twists of $GL(d)$ $L$-function
It is from ANT of Iwaniec and Kowalski that the conductor of $L$-function is defined that:
An integer $q(f) \geqslant 1$, called the conductor of $L(f, s)$, such that $\alpha_i(p) \neq 0$ for $p \nmid q(f)$ and $1 \leqslant i \leqslant d$, where
$L(f, s)=\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \lambda_f(n) n^{-s}=\prod_p\left(1-\alpha_1(p) p^{-s}\right)^{-1} \cdots\left(1-\alpha_d(p) p^{-s}\right)^{-1}$.
Now take $\chi$ be a primitive Dirichlet character modula $q$, it is obvious that the conductor of Dirichlet $L$-function is $q$ by the definition.
Take $\pi$ be some GL(d) thing attached to a $L$-function $L(s,\pi)$. From some paper, it seems that the conductor of $L(s,\pi\otimes\chi)$ is $q^d$.
For example, let $\pi$ be a modular form of weight $\kappa$ for the full modular group and suppose that $\pi$ is an eigenfunction of all the Hecke operators, then the conductor of $L(s,\pi \otimes \chi)$ is $q^2$, how can we compute the conductor from the definiton of conductor?

It depends on what the conductor of $\pi$ is. If $\pi$ has conductor $r$ and $(q,r) = 1$, then the conductor of $L(s,\pi \otimes \chi)$ is $q^d r$. If $(r,q) > 1$, then the conductor divides $q^d r$ but can be much smaller. See this paper for a systematic answer: https://doi.org/10.1216/RMJ-2019-49-4-1093

Thanks, I will see it.
